# How to prevent dynamic array from including a blank first element

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm really struggling with why my array keeps including an empty element as its first element.

I'm populating an array from the selected choices in a listbox and I keep getting an empty first element in the array.  I'm not getting any empty elements afterwards, just for the first element.

I've looked at lots of code to remove an empty element, all of which is beyond my understanding of arrays at this point, but that is not ideally for what I'm looking: `I'm looking to prevent that empty element from appearing in my array in the first place.`

Would anyone please help me understand what I need to change?  I've tried using `Option Base 1` and iterating from 1 instead of 0, but I get an error when trying to do so.  Additionally, I did `Redim` my array as `(0 To 0)` and `(0 to UBound)` as well but nothing changed from my code below.

I'm assuming it has to do with the way I'm iterating through my listbox elements but I'm not sure how to fix the issue.

```
ReDim Part_Number_Array(1 To 1) As Variant
For Selected = 0 To Part_Number_Select.ListCount - 1
    If Part_Number_Select.Selected(Selected) = True Then
        ReDim Preserve Part_Number_Array(1 To UBound(Part_Number_Array) + 1) As Variant
        'Add Part Number to the Array
        Part_Number_Array(UBound(Part_Number_Array)) = _
        Part_Number_Select.List(Selected)
        'UpperBoundCount = UBound(Part_Number_Array)
        'MsgBox "The upper bound is " & UpperBoundCount
    End If
Next Selected
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That is a known vb limitation which causes us all some "Empty/not empty" and member-count issues.

I have dealt with this by:

Define a class with Add/Delete/Find/etc methods no showing the array and provide a Count property. Also, you can use a Collection (and then there are some interesting derivatives, like the Dictionaries)

OR

OPTION BASE 0 (to be more C like) and use a _Count variable, initialized to 0, to keep track exactly how many useful items does the array hold and do Redims 0 to NewCount+1.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are redimming 1 to 1 outside the loop, then inside the loop you are redimming again before adding another element to it, then when you do add the element you are using the `ubound`. So it seems what happening is, you're redimming 1 to 1, which gives the array 1 empty slot. then, inside the loop you are redimming it  `1 to UBound(Part_Number_Array) + 1)`. the `+ 1` at the end adds another slot (ubound is currently 1, 1 + 1 = 2) and then, when you add the element you are using `Part_Number_Array(UBound(Part_Number_Array)) =` so that statement puts the element at the ubound of the array, which is 2, leaving the first spot blank.

The solution:

```
ReDim Part_Number_Array(1 To 1) As Variant
For Selected = 0 To Part_Number_Select.ListCount - 1
    If Part_Number_Select.Selected(Selected) = True Then
        'Add Part Number to the Array before redimming, thus putting the new element in the 1 empty slot

        Part_Number_Array(UBound(Part_Number_Array)) = _
        Part_Number_Select.List(Selected)
        'UpperBoundCount = UBound(Part_Number_Array)
        'MsgBox "The upper bound is " & UpperBoundCount
        ReDim Preserve Part_Number_Array(1 To UBound(Part_Number_Array) + 1) As Variant


    End If
Next Selected
```

then, after the loop you can do - `ReDim Preserve Part_Number_Array(1 To UBound(Part_Number_Array) - 1)` notice the minus 1, this will eliminate the last slot (which is empty because of having a redim statement without adding another element)

Comment: Thank you for the code!  This seems to fix the problem.  Thank you very much.